# Could not find property 'VERSION_CODE'

Tags: android, gradle

I want to use this library for my project and I got error when I try open this [library (FloatingActionButton)](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) source from Github.

I download as zip this project when I tried to open the source code to understand it, I got this error:

```
Error:(10, 0) Could not find property 'VERSION_CODE' on project ':library'.
```

Add **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

apply from: '../gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Comment: Why don't you use new support design library ?

Comment: why don't you use gradle dependency to use this library, why do you need to add it like module?

Comment: @Jaykishan Sewak - sorry, it looks silly, but I don't find sample of use this library for such menu: http://joxi.ru/52a17K1iJZMb20

Comment: if you know how this make write answer pls

Comment: Vitya, zamuchilsja s etim menu kruglim, ne umey vidno guglit. Ya uzhe podklychil ee i ona rabotaet no net docki na nee - hochu pod kapotom glyanut

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko just replace these version codes with random values :) e.g. versionCode 123 and versionName "privet"

Comment: @Vityok - delal uzhe - drugay oshibka viletaet

Answer (score 5):

import library as a module, change `versionCode` and `versionName` to random values,
add a reference to your project - add to dependencies
 
`compile project(":library")`

and remove:

> apply from: '../gradle-mvn-push.gradle'

Answer (score 2):

To use new design support library yout need to write following line in your app's gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

and in your layout.xml file write following lines

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/your_icon"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/coordinator_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        />
```

Thats it

Comment: Thank you, but I need add to this button menu like this http://joxi.ru/52a17K1iJZMb20 - and I dont found sample how do it.

Answer (score 1):

The project you downloaded doesn't seem to have an AndroidManifest file, so it doesn't have a VERSION_CODE or a VERSION_NAME. When you incorporate the code in your project, it will get them from the Manifest file in your project. Or so I would hope.

Answer (score 1):

Import library as a module by,

```
1. File-> New-> ImportModule-> SoureDirectory-> "your library path" -> ok.
2. Change versionCode and versionName to the same as in android-Floating-button/sample/build.gradle
  (copy that 2 from app build.gradle to library build.gradle)
  ( for example give: versionCode 1, versionName "1.0"), 
3. (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S) or Go to File > Project Structure > Modules --> Click on "Dependencies"
-> click on "+"(plus) -> Module Dependency -> select you lib-> "OK".
4. Remove this from build.grade in you "library"
apply from: './gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
5. Add this in you app "build.gradle" like this
dependencies {
compile project(":library")
}
```